# Require is not defined after navigating to new url

Tags: node.js, require, node-webkit

In node-webkit, I've got a table with some URL's that open in new windows. On this screen, when I type in `typeof process` I get `object` in return. However, when I click one of the links, a new node-webkit window opens and I instantly get a `require is not defined` error and when I type in `typeof process` it says `undefined`. Why is this happening? I've also tried to open it in the same window, same issue persists.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using and the stack trace for the error?

Comment: I just figured out what was wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured the answer out. Because my links were going to different domains, I had to put a `nodeRemoteHost` field in my manifest file that allows me to run node on those domains.See the [link](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/manifest-format#node-remote).